# Button not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button

I made this website; smartwasher.nl and added buttons, which work fine on every browser I have (That's all of them except IE) but the client says one of the buttons doesn't work. I don't get why and I can't properly test it because I don't have IE.

This is the HTML;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Biologisch reinigen met minimaal verbruik: de Smartwasher. Bestel de Smartwasher nu bij ons. De unieke Bio Remediation Technologie zorgt ervoor dat enzymen de koolwaterstoffen abreken tot CO2. "> 
        <title>Smartwasher</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    </head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="info.html">Informatie</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="caption">
        <h1>Biologisch reinigen met minimaal verbruik: de Smartwasher</h1>
        <p> De traditionele onderdelenreinigers maken gebruik van agressieve, vluchtige solventgedragen reinigingsvloeistoffen om olie en vet van onderdelen te verwijderen. Deze chemicaliën leiden soms tot moeilijkheden op het vlak van gezondheid, veiligheid en milieu.

Om dit op te lossen introduceren we de “milieuvriendelijke SmartWasher”.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="pics02.jpg">
            <a href="contact.html" class="boxbutton2">Nu bestellen!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS that goes with it;

```
body {
    background-image:url('bg.png');
    width:100%;
    border-top:10px solid black;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:helvetica;
}

a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
    color:#d1d1d1;
}

.active {
    color:#d1d1d1;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    top:0px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.header {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#28518d;
    height:60px;
    margin:0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}

.nav {
    margin: 0px auto;
    color:#fff;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:1.2em;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-size:1.4em;
    padding-right:2.0em;
}

.nav ul li:last-child {
    padding-right:0em;
}

.content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:900px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:4em;
    height:26em;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}

.caption {
    width:30%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#515151;
    padding:2.1em;
    padding-right:0;
    float:left;
    font-size:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.caption p {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.3em;
}

.caption h1 {
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#28518d;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

.image {
     display:inline;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:3em;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    width: 58%;
}

.image img {
      max-width:100% !important;
    max-height:100% !important;
    display:block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.box {
    width:180px;
    display:block;
    margin: 2em;
    float:left;
}

.box h1{
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#28518d;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

.box p{
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.3em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

.boxholder {
    margin-left:3em;
    padding-top:3em;
}

.footer {
    margin-top:4em;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#28518d;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
border-bottom:10px solid black;
}

.thanks {
    margin-top:4em;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#28518d;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
border-bottom:10px solid black;
    position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
}

.footer p {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:2em;
    padding-top:1.5em;
    font-size:0.9em;
}

.boxbutton2 {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#28518d;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    margin:4em;
    z-index:999;
     position:absolute;
     top:28em;

}.boxbutton2:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
    color:#485d7c;
}.boxbutton2:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.boxbutton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#28518d;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;


}.boxbutton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.boxbutton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


.contact h1 {
    font-size: 35px; color: #445668; text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
}

label {
     width: 95px;font-size: 16px; color: #445668; 
     text-align:left;
    text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    padding-left:4em;
}

input {
    width: 50%; height: 35px; padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px;
    background: #28518d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #28518d 0%, #28518d 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#28518d), color-stop(20%,#28518d)); /* webkit */
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71;
}
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;  
    }
    input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b; 
    }

textarea {
    width: 50%; height: 170px; padding: 12px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
    background: #28518d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #28518d 0%, #28518d 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#28518d), color-stop(20%,#28518d)); /* webkit */
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71; 
}
    textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;  
    }
    textarea:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b; 
    }


input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%; height: 52px; padding: 10px 15px; margin: 0 4em 3em 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border: 1px solid #28518d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4270b4 0%, #28518d 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4270b4), color-stop(100%,#28518d)); /* webkit */
    cursor: pointer;
}

fieldset {
    border:none;
}

.contact {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:60%;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:4em;
    height:auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
padding-left:4em;
padding-top:2em;

}

.center {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:3em;
}

.email {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

On the index I also have another set of buttons and the client says they work, while I think they are exactly the same buttons;

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="boxholder">
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Huidvriendelijk</h1>
            <p>De Smartwasher gebruikt alleen pH-neutrale vloeistoffen, aanraking met de huid is dus geen probleem.</p>
            <a href="info.html" class="boxbutton">Meer informatie</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Geen schadelijke dampen</h1>
            <p>De Smartwasher stoot geen Solventen uit, uw werknemers staan dus nooit in schadelijke dampen. Het gebruik van mondkapjes is niet nodig.</p>
            <a href="info.html" class="boxbutton">Meer informatie</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Niet brandbaar</h1>
            <p>De Smartwasher maakt geen gebruik van brandbare vloeistoffen. Dit is niet alleen veiliger maar zorgt ook voor een vereenvoudigde wetgeving.</p>
            <a href="info.html" class="boxbutton">Meer informatie</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy;2013 Van Rheenen Haarlem,
Groothandel voor automotive en industrie. Importeur voor de automotive branche in Nederland.<br> Prijzen genoemd op de website zijn exclusief btw.</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I'm quite puzzled and really don't get what is causing the error. I'm hoping someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: Which "button" does not work? What exactly do you mean by "does not work"?  Which version of IE?

Comment: Can't use  `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` on IE7, might cause the client to see some random stuff

Comment: Actually...
The link is the same for all the buttons, i.e., `info.html`, because of which you might think that they are the "same". But all of them are independent of each other and are in no way related except for the link being the same...
So the buttons AREN'T the same. Secondly, the buttons are working quite well in IE.

Comment: Use BrowserStack to test your web in IE, it's free for 30 minutes and up to 3 months if you take advantage from modern.ie promotion

Comment: RelevantUsername, I'll try replacing that, thanks. The 'boxbutton2' is not working, as in it is not linking anywhere, not taking you anywhere.

Comment: Galen, yes I tried that, saw the button 'failing', and that's it. I can't find what's causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe in newer versions, but in IE7 and 8 it was failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
.boxbutton2:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

So remove it, and it works as expected.

That rule is causing your link to jump, so my assumption would be when it's disturbing the way IE handles the link.

You could also neaten up your CSS a little bit, like so:

```
.footer,.thanks {
    margin-top:4em;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#28518d;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
}

.thanks {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

and also:

```
.boxbutton,.boxbutton2 {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#28518d;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.boxbutton:hover,.boxbutton2:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.boxbutton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.boxbutton2 {
    margin:4em;
    z-index:999;
    position:absolute;
    top:28em;
}
```

So instead of duplicating the CSS you're applying it to both classes.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, this solved it and thank you for the tip on my CSS!